# ¿Como crear un formData.append para poder enviar inputs de tipo File?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, bootstrap

Deseo enviar un **input type="file"** desde un **form**, para enviar todos los datos de mi formulario utilizo el [formData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData), el cual creo desde cero para poder capturar cada uno de los datos que existe en mi formulario y recibirlo en una pagina [php](/questions/tagged/php), en esta pagina puedo capturar todos los datos que estan en el formulario pero no logro capturar el archivo, tengo lo siguiente:

**JS**

Función donde creó el FormData:

```
function dataForm_Archivos(formulario){
    var nuevoFormulario = new FormData();   
    $(formulario).find(':input').each(function() {
        var elemento= this;
        //Si recibe tipo archivo 'file'
        if(elemento.type === 'file'){
            if(elemento.value !== ''){
               var file_data = $('input[type="file"]')[0].files;
               for (var i = 0; i < file_data.length; i++) {
                  nuevoFormulario.append(elemento.name, file_data[i]);
               }
            }            
         }
     }
}
```

función dónde llega el id del formulario y lo envió a través de [ajax](/questions/tagged/ajax):

```
function registrarDocumentacion(formulario){

var datosForm = dataForm_Archivos(formulario);
var request = $.ajax({
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    data: datosForm,                         
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'url',
    beforeSend:function(){

     }

    });

    request.done(function(datos) { 

    });
 }
```

**HTML**

```
<form role="form" action='#?' id="registroDocumentacion" method="post">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label">Adjuntar Archivo</label>
        <input type="file" id="arcAdjunto"  name="arcAdjunto" class="filestyle" placeholder="Asunto" onchange="validarArchivo('#arcAdjunto');">
        <h5><small>Recuerde, los tipos de archivos permitidos son: png, gif, jpg, jpeg, docx, xls, xlsx, docs, pdf</small></h5>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
 <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 text-left m-t-20">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary waves-effect waves-light" id="enviarDoc" > Enviar <i class="fa fa-send" aria-hidden="true"></i>   </button>
          </div>
    </div>
</form>


<script type="text/javascript">
   $('#enviarDoc').click(function(event) {
     registrarDocumentacion('#registroDocumentacion')
   });
</script>
```

**UPDATE**

Logre hacerlo de esta manera

```
function dataForm_Archivos(formulario){
    var nuevoFormulario = new FormData();   
    $(formulario).find(':input').each(function() {
        var elemento= this;
        //Si recibe tipo archivo 'file'
        if(elemento.type === 'file'){
           if(elemento.value !== ''){
              for(var i=0; i< $('#'+elemento.id).prop("files").length; i++){
                  nuevoFormulario.append(elemento.name, $('#'+elemento.id).prop("files")[i]);
               }
            }              
         }
     }
  return nuevoFormulario;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Puedes usar para esto el; FormData Objects, aquí te voy a dejar un ejemplo:

```
 var formData = new FormData();

 formData.append("archivoDelUsuario", fileInputElement.files[0]); //Aquí capturas el fileInput seleccionado por el usuario
 var archivoBlob = new Blob([content], { type: "text/xml"}); //creamos un archivo tipo blob
 formData.append("elArchivo", archivoBlob); //listo agregamos el archivo
```

Este código fue consultado y en su mayoria extraido de la documentación oficial de [Developer Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects)

Answer (score 1):

En el ejemplo que pones tu función `dataForm_Archivos(formulario)` parece tener la lógica correcta, excepto que no devuelve nada (necesita `return nuevoFormulario;` al final de la función) ya que `var nuevoFormulario = new FormData();` es local a la función (no existe fuera de ella); así `var datosForm = dataForm_Archivos(formulario);` realmente no recoge nada.

Prueba con:

```
function dataForm_Archivos(formulario){
    var nuevoFormulario = new FormData();   
    $(formulario).find(':input').each(function() {
        var elemento= this;
        //Si recibe tipo archivo 'file'
        if(elemento.type === 'file'){
            if(elemento.value !== ''){
               var file_data = $('input[type="file"]')[0].files;
               for (var i = 0; i < file_data.length; i++) {
                  nuevoFormulario.append(elemento.name, file_data[i]);
               }
            }            
         }
     }

    return nuevoFormulario;
}
```

Comment: Gracias, si en realidad faltaba el return pero cuando capturó el campo en [tag:php] no me retorna nada, encontré otra forma de hacerlo, actualizaré el post para colocarla

Answer (score 0):

Si es que todavia no solucionaste esto.
También te faltaba el `enctype="multipart/form-data"` en el

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data"></form>
```